# Telescoping series sum

Tags: calculus

I am suppose to find $\sum_{n = 3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$

I am suppose to rewrite it as a telescoping series, but that isn't really defined so I don't know how to do that so I just copied the wikipedia page and get

$$\frac{-1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1}$$

Ok whatever, I try and find the sum and i see both terms diverge. Is that the answer?

Comment: No, that isn't the answer. Start writing the first few terms with the difference, $(\frac12 - \frac13) + (\frac13 - \frac14) + \dotsb$. See something?

Comment: Nope. I don't get it.

Comment: I can see that 1/n diverges, how can I find the sum of something that diverges?

Comment: @John Look at the sum Daniel wrote above. What would the next term be?

Comment: Look at the partial sums (with *finitely* many terms). What cancels? Find $S_m=\sum_{n=3}^m (1/(n(n-1))$ explicitly. Then find the limit of the $S_m$ as $m$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: I like $\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ better. The sum of the first few terms is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}$. Now is it clear?

Comment: I see what happens but I don't understand how adding two series that diverge can then converge.

Comment: @John: Addition doesn't work the way you think for infinite series - *in general*, you can't rearrange things arbitrarily. For example, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges to $\infty$, and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ diverges to $-\infty$, but the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0$$
is obviously convergent.

Comment: Yes it happens. For example $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{n+1}$ they both diverge but $(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}=0$ converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your sum can be written as

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Now, let's see what happens when we examine the first few terms in the series. If we add up the first three terms we have

$$\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\right).$$

Notice that everything but the first and last terms cancel. What could you then conclude about the sum

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=3}^N\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the partial sums.

Since $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}
=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n}$,
the sum of the first $M$ terms is

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 3}^M \frac{1}{n(n-1)}
&=\frac1{2*3}+\frac1{3*4}+\frac1{4*5}+...+\frac1{(M-1)*M}\\
&=(\frac1{2}-\frac1{3})+(\frac1{3}-\frac1{4})+(\frac1{4}-\frac1{5})+...+(\frac1{M-1}-\frac1{M})\\
&=\frac1{2}+(-\frac1{3}+\frac1{3})+(-\frac1{4}+\frac1{4})+...
+(-\frac1{M-1}+\frac1{M-1})-\frac1{M}
\quad\quad (*)\\
&=\frac1{2}-\frac1{M}\\
\end{align}
$

The rearrangement in the line marked
"$(*)$" is allowed because
the sum has a finite number of terms,
and finite sums can be rearranged in any way.

Note that all terms except the first
$\frac1{2}$ and last $\frac1{M}$
are canceled out,
so the final result
for the partial sum of the first $M$ terms is 
$\sum_{n = 3}^M \frac{1}{n(n-1)}
=\frac1{2}-\frac1{M}
$.

The limit of this as
$M \to \infty$
is 
$\frac1{2}$.

Comment: Be very careful with rearranging the order of operations in infinite series. This is not always a valid thing to do.