# Sum ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n(n+3)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine if the series converges or diverges. If it converges what does it converge to?

${\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n(n+3)}}$

Here's what I have been able to figure out

By the limit comparison test ${\sum\frac{1}{x^2}}$

${\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4n^2}{n^2 + 3n} = 4\Rightarrow}$ Convergence

But I can't figure out how to tell what it converges to, it's not an alternating series, or a geometric series that I can tell. And we haven't yet covered taylor series. It might be a power series, but I don't see any x value to tell what it converges to.

Comment: Hint. The given series is telescoping.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449108/telescoping-series-sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{4}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+3}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{4}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)+\dfrac{4}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+2}\right)+\dfrac{4}{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+2}-\dfrac{1}{n+3}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a positive integer then,
if $m > a$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(a, m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n(n+a)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{a}(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+a})\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{m} (\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+a})\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n+a}\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=a+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=a+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{a} \dfrac1{n}+\sum_{n=a+1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=a+1}^{m} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=m+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{a} \dfrac1{n}-\sum_{n=m+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
s(a, m)-\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{a} \dfrac1{n}
&=-\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=m+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
\text{so that}\\
|s(a, m)-\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{a} \dfrac1{n}|
&=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=m+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{n}\\
&\le\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=m+1}^{a+m} \dfrac1{m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\dfrac{a}{m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{m+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\lim_{m \to \infty} s(a, m)
=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{a} \dfrac1{n}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that it can be showed that, in general (it's quite evident why this happens):
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{(i+p)} \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{p} \frac{1}{i}$$
But see that:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{(n(n+3))} = 4 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3n} - \frac{1}{3(n+3)} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+3} \right)$$
In this way, $p = 3$, then we have:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+3} \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^{3} \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+3} \right) = 73/45$$
Logo a sequência converge.